# Angular 7 integration with StencilJS problem - Cannot find module 'test-components/dist/loader'

Tags: angular, angular7, stenciljs

I am trying to integrate my Angular 7 project with StencilJS so I can use custom web components/elements, and I'm following the integration guide on the StencilJS website [here](https://stenciljs.com/docs/angular).

I'm on the instructions that say:

> A component collection built with Stencil includes a main function
>   that is used to load the components in the collection. That function
>   is called `defineCustomElements()` and it needs to be called once during
>   the bootstrapping of your application. One convenient place to do this
>   is in `main.ts` as such:

I tried importing `defineCustomElements()` in my `main.ts` file as follows:

[image]

But I'm getting the following error:

[image]

```
[ts] Cannot find module 'test-components/dist/loader'
```

Do I have to install this module using `npm install`?

If so, why doesn't the guide include that instruction?

Comment: How are you distributing your `test-components` module? i.e. did you publish it to npm, and install it into your Angular project? https://stenciljs.com/docs/distribution#using-your-component-in-a-framework

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

$ npm i web-social-share

$ In app module/feature module in your app add the CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
   .........
  ],
  schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
```

Then finally in main.ts

```
import { defineCustomElements } from 'web-social-share/dist/loader';
.....
defineCustomElements(window);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error.

For me, I was publishing my stencil web component to npm and then installing it into my project.

I had the same "Cannot find module" when **I forgot to run `npm run build` before `npm publish`**.

Answer (score -1):

@Kingamere Yes, you need to install the webcomponent first in your project. Steps to integrate a stencil webcomponent should be as follows:

1. Install component in angular project (`npm install <module-name>`)
2. Enable custom element schema in app.module.ts (`schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]`)
3. import component in app.component.ts (`import * as <name> from 'test-components/dist/loader';)`
4. Register component to the registry (`<name>.defineCustomElements(window);`)
5. Use selector of your stencil component wherever you want in your project